# Unable to connect to database?

Tags: php, mysql

This PHP is not working for me, it will not connect
Here is my code

```
<?php
$server   = "localhost";
$database = "induadmi_db";
$username = "induadmi_main";
$password = "password";

$mysqlConnection = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
if (!$mysqlConnection)
{
  echo "Please try later.";
}
else
{
mysql_select_db($database, $mysqlConnection);
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this style:`sample one` and refer this following `link`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: its a `sample one`, you should mention your `password` and `username` of mysql

Answer (score -2):

Works fine on my end with my own connection parameters..

You need to change this block to see the exact error...

```
if (!$mysqlConnection)
{
  die(mysql_error());
}
```

---

This (`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used. Switching to `PreparedStatements` is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

So nuff said..

### Switch to PDO..

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=induadmi_db;host=localhost';
$database = "induadmi_db";
$username = "induadmi_main";
$password = "password";
try
{
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password ,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Now I am getting Access denied for user 'induadmi_main'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Switched to PDO, now getting Connection failed: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'induadmi_main'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Good. Seems like you have not set a password.. Try sending the password blank `$password = "";`

Comment: Connection failed: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'induadmi_main'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: This is has to do with your username and password. Are you sure the username and password is correct ? if not create a new user.